# How can 120*160mm be a "landscape" format?

Tags: print-design

My client requested a 120*160mm landscape format. This is a contradiction in terms to me, because in "120*160mm" the "120" is the width and "160" the height. In my mind the only possible way to properly frame would be: "160*120mm landscape format".

Or is there some convention or tradition in print vocabulary that I am unaware of?

Comment: No, your client simply didn't put width before height. Simply a common error.

Comment: @KMSTR agreed. Although it's just a short comment, I think that's worthy of an answer if you add a link to an explanation of the convention

Comment: As I found out, there is more than one convention. This will take some research.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, paper sizes are given in width before height (e.g. [Wiki on paper sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size)) most of the time. This is contrasted by the usage "always put height before width" I could find in some cases of image descriptions. But I was unable to produce the referenced "Fine Art Standards" that people described. Wikipedia themselves defined image dimensions this way for Visual Arts ([Wiki on Image captions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Visual_arts)), but contradicts in it's [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Francisco_de_Goya_y_Lucientes_054.jpg).

As for your case, **landscape** is the only clearly defined term, I would go by it.

Comment: Agree. In paper sizes as in math you give the With (X axis) and then the Height (Y axis). I could not find a reference for the Fine Arts Standards, but I just read about it some days ago. :o)

But I think it is just a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Many clients will give dimensions shorter-side first because it sounds better with the numbers in order, specify which is which with "landscape" and expect the designer to do whatever's necessary.

That is, "160x220" specifies the size, and "landscape" the orientation. They don't know there's a "standard". They only know what size they want.

It is the case that with most paper being used in "portrait" orientation, *shorter* × *longer* **is** the standard form of *width* × *height*. They just carry on using that regardless.

Comment: I have actually read the opposite as well "always give the bigger number first" but as with all the other conventions I see no real point in it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually. **all** measurements are given properly as **width x height x depth/length**. This is standard construction format, it's not *just* for paper. THis standard is used so that *everyone* constructing *anything*, anywhere could read the series and know the correct dimensions.

However, I agree with others, many aren't aware of this and if they state "Landscape" (or portrait) specifically and the numbers are in the incorrect order, they merely formatted the numbers incorrectly. Any orientation designation should take precedence over the number format.

Because there's *so much* confusion regarding this with people, you should **never be afraid to ask** specifically what is meant, if you are unsure.

> So you want the layout 160mm wide and 120mm tall, correct?